# Почему, когда в TabLayout более 1 вкладки, пишет HotizontalScrollView can host only one direct child?

Tags: android, tab

```
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/today" />


        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Если добавить ещё один TabItem, то выскакивает ошибка. Нигде не нашёл решения, про TabLayout нигде ничего не написано

Вот весь layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mon" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tue" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wed" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/thu" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fri" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/weekViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="8dp"
        app:itemPaddingTop="8dp"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnav"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(да, я знаю, что наверно, нужно было использовать фрагменты вместо лэйаута-в-лэйауте, но в моём случае так будет и проще, и быстрее)

Comment: Так у вас там не HotizontalScrollView если есть понятно что ошибка будет, потому что HotizontalScrollView не может больше одного вложенного элемента иметь

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать один любой Layout на ваше усмотрение (например, LinearLayout) внутри TabLayout и использовать его в качестве контейнера для всех ваших TabItem. Данная ошибка возникает из-за наследования TabLayout HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Тогда `InflateException`: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout

Comment: Вы правы. Что касается Вашего кода, у меня всё работает при добавлении 3-х TabItem в сам TabLayout. Скорее всего, ошибка не тут.

Comment: Забыл уточнить: приложение-то запускается и работает, но андроид студия из-за ошибки перестаёт показывать мою разметку в редакторе

Comment: Отправьте код до корневого Layout. Проблема точно связана с остальной разметкой.

Comment: Отправил лэйаут

Comment: Я протестировал. У меня ошибок не выдаёт. Предлагаю Вам пересоздать activity-файл и поменять API version of preview. Скорее всего у Вас стоит 34.

Comment: Версия превью ничего не меняет - хоть 33, хоть 34. Файл потом, если что, пересоздам, а пока на время работы с ним буду просто убирать оттуда вкладки. Главное, что ничего фатального нет. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: К сожалению, не за что)